# Filter on reduced values from a column?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm sorry this is titled so horribly.

I have a category column in a sheet (col H) and in another sheet I've got the unique values in those columns with `unique(sheetname!H)`

How do I get only the categories (col H values) whose value in, say, col F, is 'credit'?

A given category will *always* have a given col-F value: will *always* be credit or debit. And will always belong to a certain person, as well. Say the person's name is in column B. How do I display the person who "belongs" to that category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using queries should make this simple.

Something like this should work:

`=QUERY(A:H, "select H where F='credit'",0)`

More details on how the information is stored would help.

The first parameter is the range of cells to perform the query on. The second parameter is the [query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage). The third is the number of header rows at the top of data.

More info on QUERY: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

To display the names in column B along with the categories, you can use:

`=QUERY(A:H, "select B,H where F='credit'",0)`

Comment: Thanks! I have header rows in the data source so I had to replace the 1 with 0

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
={H1; FILTER(H2:H; F2:F="credit")}
```

for unique:

```
={H1; UNIQUE(FILTER(H2:H; F2:F="credit"))}
```

Comment: That's cool and seems a little more concise. Can you explain the arguments?

Comment: sure. array brackets {} for constructing an array in which H1 is the header row and under it we put all (unique) values from H column where F column is credit